# Why do we use database and not store the information in variables (server)

Tags: java, database, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a web application with Spring Boot, I have a list of people names that gets updates sometimes when I have a call to some API and do calculation.
The web application is always live and I have a field: `List<String> people` with the people names as I said.
I have clients that want to get the list every now and then so in the `Controller` I have a method that returns this list.

**The question is:** Do I need to store this list in database? Why? I can keep working with the local field and return this in the `Controller` method, am I wrong?

I'm not sure why I need database when I'm working with web application, why not to work with variables and store the information in the variables.

Comment: You should probably read something about [persistence](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/What_is_Java_persistence%3F)

Comment: Nothing is mandatory, its all about how your application is designed. Database is used to persist the data and share among with other users as well.

Comment: Ok, it's just looks like database is mandatory in every application. so I need database only if I want the data to be saved even if the application shuts down or crashes?

Comment: You need database (or any other storage) only if your application has internal state and you want to store it and restore after failures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It totally depends on your expectations from the application. If you want the data to be persisted in case of application shutdown or crash somewhere i.e. you don't want to lose data you should use databases. If the data is not needed to be persisted then you don't need to use database.

Comment: If the application shutdown or crash then the client can't get the data from the server, so I don't need to keep the data because in that case I will just get the data again in the server, anyway the data gets updated every 72 hours.